# Subquery returns more than 1 row. Using SQL select to update a different tables results

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a column in the following table 'jobqueue' using the results from a SELECT query performed on the 'mdtinfo' table.

The column I am trying to update is called ignore and I need to set the value to 1 from its default of 0.

```
update jobqueue
set jobqueue.`ignore`= '1'
   where (SELECT JobQueue_job_queue_id
    FROM mdtinfo
    WHERE product_name  = 'Example')
```

The above query returns the following error: SQL Error (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row.

When running the select query on it's own it returns results successfully.

Comment: So, do you disagree with MySQL that the given subquery returns more than one row? Or do you agree but think you should still be allowed to write the query you did? Put simply: What is your question? We can infer that you simply made a syntax error, but as written, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I agree it should return more than one row but I am unsure why I am unable to update the required column ? I am not familiar with SQL and was unable to find the answer with a quick look around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, a value of zero appearing in a `WHERE` clause means false.

So, `UPDATE something SET col=val WHERE (SELECT colx FROM sometable)` has the potential to be a valid query. If the inner `SELECT` gets just one row, and its `colx` column has the value 0, the update won't do anything. If the `colx` column has a nonzero value the query means `UPDATE something SET col=val WHERE true`. Accordingly, *every row in `sometable` will be updated.* I doubt that's what you want.

If the inner `SELECT` happens to return more than one row, the query isn't valid. You'll get the error 1242 you actually received.

(This business of interpreting numbers as Boolean values causes MySQL to accept some otherwise dodgy query syntax, like the syntax in your question.)

I guess you want to retrieve the `job_queue_id` values for the row or rows you actually want to update.  So try something like this.

```
update jobqueue
   set jobqueue.`ignore`= '1'
 where jobqueue.job_queue_id IN (SELECT JobQueue_job_queue_id
                                   FROM mdtinfo
                                  WHERE product_name  = 'Example')
```

I guessed you have a column `jobqueue.job_queue_id`. You didn't tell us what columns you have in `jobqueue`.

Comment: Hi O. Jones, Thank you for your detailed answer. Your above query has worked and set the required 'ignores' to 1. I am not familiar with SQL so this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
update jobqueue
set jobqueue.`ignore`= '1'
    where jobqueue.`job_queue_id` IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(JobQueue_job_queue_id)
    FROM mdtinfo
    WHERE product_name  = 'Example' GROUP BY product_name)
```

you should write column name in where condition.

Comment: True, but likely not OP's problem based off of the error.

Comment: It likely would, yes. But we don't know enough about the question anyway

Comment: I agree that is likely a valid answer, but I am not the OP

Comment: let him try first if it will not work we will have a proper question.

Comment: Hi Prateik, Kchason, thank you for your responses. I tried the above query and it ran without any errors but did not update the 'ignore' column in the jobqueue table.

Comment: please check with the updated query again and let us know if is there any error or something else

Comment: and please check if **JobQueue.JobQueue_job_queue_id** and job_queue_id both are match in both table.

Comment: Hi Prateik, the edited query produces the SQL Error (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: JobQueue.JobQueue_job_queue_id &  job_queue_id are both correct

Comment: try to fetch records using a subquery to check which records should be updated